# What are the benefits of using KnockoutJS when compared to AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, knockout.js

Is there any feature in KnockoutJS which could challenge or at least better in comparison with AngularJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can compare knockoutJS with only a part of AngularJS.
Angular is a fully fledged framework whereas knockoutJS only concentrates on databinding.

I will not say AngularJS is better to use compared to KnockoutJS because KnockoutJS is designed to only work on data-binding part whereas using Angular we can design an entire application.

If you want to work only on data-binding, we can just use knockoutJS, whereas if are starting a new application you can go with AngularJS.

Answer (score -1):

One little aspect:

- AngularJS is more powerful in DOM manipulation.
- we can use a feature (model) in AngularJS within text of elements(between start and end tags); like:

  {{model}}

here `{{model}}` is AngularJS feature. [Data binding is more powerful in Angular JS]

But, we cannot do the same with knockout.js: we only have to use knockout js for HTML within element's attributes; like:

```
<div data-bind="knockout code"> </div>
```

Another thing which i know is: AngularJS provides MVC like structure, whereas knockout is MVVM.

Comment: KnockoutJS provides extensibility points that allow you customize the binding syntax. So it is possible to do `{{model}}` in KnockoutJS as shown in this [extension](http://mbest.github.io/knockout.punches/).

Comment: Syntactic sugar aside, one the main differences between knockout and angular's databinding approaches is that in knockout you have one-way binding by default and have to explicitly opt into two-way binding in with observables. And in angular you have two-way binding by default and have to explicitly opt into one-way binding.